# How do I attach the client certificate to a SOAP request?

Tags: vb.net, ssl, iis, soap, x509

I have a VB.NET website configured in IIS to use client certificate authentication.

When a user opens website url, he gets a popup to choose the certificate. Once the user is on the web page there is a button, clicking this will make a SOAP request to a 3rd party.

Presently I am able to use a single certificate stored on the server to make the SOAP request (by attaching the certificate). Thus the same certificate is used irrespective of which user clicks on the button.

How do I attach the client certificate of the respective user to a SOAP request? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I attach the client certificate of the respective user to a SOAP request? Is this possible?

simply attaching the public certificate of client makes little sense. If you need to co-sign the SOAP request with client certificate, then you need to send unsigned SOAP request to client (say, client downloads the request from your web site), sign it, send to server, allow the server to co-sign the SOAP request and then submit this SOAP request to 3rd party.

You cannot upload client certificate to server in order to make SOAP signing on server. It is unsupported and vulnerable approach. Client certificate's private key (which is used to sign data) MUST NEVER leave client machine/device. If you need to sign anything with client certificate, signing operation must be performed on that client only.